# Lost changes when edit after approving suggested edit

Tags: bug, ios-app

Question [RecyclerView Androud](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/653874/176217) was edited by me via [**accept and edit**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/170812) in the suggested edit queue. Then I open it in iOS app and saw result view:

> [image: post]

and edit history:

> [image: history]

All was fine. But when I tried to fix some overlooked mistakes and tap **Edit** I saw old (before accepting a suggested edit) revision:

> [image: edit]

If this is due to a caching, why I saw l last version in read mode, and previous on edit?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)